# Why is my facebook like button applying to the "social plugins" page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have added a facebook like button to my site at http://forkmyreligion.com.  I have triple checked all the settings for the app on my developers.facebook page and I'm pretty sure its all correct - the domain is correct, the website url is correct and I have the correct app id for the application.
The problem though is that clicking on the like button results in the user liking the facebook social plugins page rather than my page.
Any ideas what the problem might be?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Like button on your page is Liking the social plugins page because the Like button on your page has a `data-href` parameter which is explicitly configuring the like button to like that URL:

You have this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>
```

You need to set the `data-href` to the URL you want the button to display and increment the like count of.

This parameter is mentioned on the [Like button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) and the example in the documentation is the URL `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/`

Comment: Dude, I feel like such a numpty!!!  I've added several like buttons correctly to other apps but somehow I missed this this time.